# Разбиение чисел на простые множители

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11, простые-числа, факторизация

Как быстро разбить числа до 10ˆ18 на простые множители?

Comment: Изучить высшую алгебру?

Comment: если не разобрались с наивным алгоримтом попытайтесь сначала его осилить - потом переходите на быстре алгоритмы

Comment: например используя двойное решето эратосфена... а вообще способов много.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Циклом : использовать функцию ( что данное число простое), если ответ неудовлетворительный, то число делить на найденный делитель. Дальше продолжать пока оставшееся число не стало простым.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, для гарантии - надо проверить делимость на простые числа до 10^9. Их примерно 48 миллионов - не так уж и много :) Так что можно даже простым перебором по всем простым числам, простите за каламбур.

Ну, и почитайте что-нибудь о [факторизации целых чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB).

**Update**
Вот, пользуясь выходным :), набросал программку. На моей машине решетом Эратосфена строит таблицу простых чисел до 1e9 за немного меньше 6 секунд, после чего разлагает на множители числа порядка 9e17 за 0.23с в среднем; минимально - мгновенно (микросекунды), максимально - 0.45 с. Конечно, не скажу, что это быстро, но... Компилировал 64-разрядную программу.

```
constexpr inline unsigned long pow2(unsigned long i) { return 1 << i; }
inline unsigned long isqrt(unsigned long a)
{
    unsigned long x = a;
    for(unsigned long z = 0; x != z; )
    {
        z = x;
        x = (x + a/x)/2;
    }
    return x;
}

constexpr unsigned long MAX_LIM = 1000000000; //pow2(31) - 1;
constexpr unsigned long ARR_LIM = (MAX_LIM >> 6) + 1;
const     unsigned long SQR_LIM = isqrt(MAX_LIM);;

unsigned long primes[ARR_LIM] = { 0 }; // 0 - простое, 1 - составное

auto set_primes = [](unsigned long idx) { primes[idx >> 6] |= pow2((idx&0x0000003F)>>1); };
auto get_primes = [](unsigned long idx) { return primes[idx >> 6] &  pow2((idx&0x0000003F)>>1); };

vector<unsigned long> Primes;

void makePrimes()
{
    for(unsigned long j = 9; j <= MAX_LIM; j += 3)
    {
        if (j%2) set_primes(j);
    }
    for(unsigned long i = 5; i <= SQR_LIM; i += 6)
    {
        if (get_primes(i)) continue;
        for(unsigned long j = i * i; j <= MAX_LIM; j += i)
        {
            if (j%2) set_primes(j);
        }
    }
    for(unsigned long i = 7; i <= SQR_LIM; i += 6)
    {
        if (get_primes(i)) continue;
        for(unsigned long j = i * i; j <= MAX_LIM; j += i)
        {
            if (j%2) set_primes(j);
        }
    }
    Primes.reserve(55000000);
    Primes.push_back(2);
    for(unsigned long i = 3; i <= MAX_LIM; i+=2)
    {
        if (get_primes(i)) continue;
        Primes.push_back(i);
    }

}


vector<unsigned long> * factors(long long L, vector<unsigned long> * v = 0)
{
    if (v == 0) v = new vector<unsigned long>;
    if (L == 1) return v;
    for(auto f: Primes)
    {
        if (f*f > L) {
            v->push_back(L);
            return v;
        }
        if (L%f == 0)
        {
            v->push_back(f);
            return factors(L/f,v);
        }
    }
    return v;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    makePrimes();
    printf("Total primes = %d\n",Primes.size());

    for(long long i = 900000000000000000ll; i < 900000000000001000ll; ++i)
    {
        vector<unsigned long> * f = factors(i);
        for(auto x: *f)
        {
            printf("%lu ",x);
        }
        printf("%lld\n",i);
        delete f;
    }

}
```

Comment: а это быстрее будет чем перебирать делители ?

Comment: А это и есть перебор делителей...

Comment: ну реализовать то по разному можно

Comment: @ampawd Ну, гляньте мою простейшую реализацию перебора...

Comment: а на каком CPU запускалась ваша программа ?

Comment: вот читаю код...раз уж взялись за микрооптимизации, то тогда можно было ещё поменять `j%2` на `j & 1` остатотак от деления всё таки дорогая операция.

Comment: @ampawd Интереса ради посмотрите ассемблерный код... Например, тут: https://godbolt.org/g/xbcl06

Comment: @ampawd Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz - так Win сообщает :)

Comment: да, действительно компилятор генериует тот же ассемблерный код что и для `j & 1` ) наверняка  майкрософтовский компилятор сделает тоже самое - во всяком случае, эта микрооптимизация не столь важна, вот я запустил ваш код на 32 битной `Windows` машине c процессором `Intel Core(TM) 2 Duo E4500 @ 2.20 Hz` и одно только получение простых чисел заняло где то 320 секунд.

Comment: @ampawd чем в 50 раз - вряд ли дело в процессоре.

Comment: а в чём может быть дело ? я думаю вы циклов много понаставили :) Кстати ради интереса не могли бы вы запустить и сказать время выполнения моей реализации (см мой ответ тут) разбиения на Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz ? спс

Comment: @ampawd Увы, ссылки в комментарии не оказалось...

Answer (score 0):

мой вариант разбиения - по сути тотже перебор делителей среди простых получающиеся решетом эратосфена.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

constexpr unsigned long N = 1000000000;
bool grid[N + 2];
unsigned long primes[51000000];
unsigned long primesCount;

inline void factors(unsigned long num)
{
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < primesCount; ++i)
    {
        while (num % primes[i] == 0)
        {
            std::cout << primes[i] << ' ';
            num /= primes[i];
        }       
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    grid[0] = grid[1] = true;   
    grid[2] = false;

    for (unsigned long p = 3, k; p*p <= N; p += 2)
    {
        if (! grid[p])
        {
            for (k = p*p; k <= N; k += p)           
                grid[k] = true;         
        }
    }
    primes[primesCount++] = 2;
    for (unsigned long p = 3, k; p <= N; p += 2)
    {
        if (! grid[p]) primes[primesCount++] = p;
    }
    for (unsigned long long num = 900000000000000000ll; num < 900000000000000100ll; ++num)
    {
        std::cout << num << " - ";
        factors(num);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    auto elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<
        std::chrono::milliseconds
    >(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);

    std::cout << elapsedTime.count() / 1000.0f << '\n'
              << "primes count: " << primesCount << '\n';
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем то железо, но: http://pastebin.com/SM4MQJKn

Comment: И вариант Harry:  http://pastebin.com/JXRc1rE3

Comment: @PinkTux очень странно, вариант Harry у меня порядка 320 секунд высчитывал только простые

Comment: @PinkTux ну, у меня вывод использует `cout` если это убрать на `printf` немного быстрее будет

Comment: Это не принципиально. Даже если убрать таймер и вывод из исходников - разница мелкая. Для полной ясности нужно просто под профайлером гонять, ну и что-то вроде gcov можно посмотреть.